# C: Comparison between value initialization during definition & assignment after it

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization

Just a question from curiosity. In C we can initialize value directly or assign after defining the variable. like

```
char* pStr = NULL;
```

or

```
char* pStr;
pStr = NULL;
```

functionality-wise they are similar but is there any difference after compilation. Is extra instruction cycle is required for the later or modern compiler are intelligent enough to optimize.

N.B: I am reviewing a old codebase where the second case is being used extensively. Thats why I am curious, if I can get real change by changing the code in all the places.

Comment: 1.) there's no language C/C++! The code you show *happens* to be valid in two languages. 2.) they are **not** "similar in every aspect". The first is initialization, the second is an assignment. Do this with a local variable and add a `static` storage class modifier to see the difference.

Comment: there is an awesome tool that can help to answer such questions. Take a look at what the compiler outputs for the two here: https://godbolt.org/

Comment: You are on the wrong site. The site you are looking for is [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/LqMSBJ), not stackoverflow.

Comment: @tobi303 that's only half the truth ... different compilers can do different things with this. If the observable behavior of the assignment is indeed the same as an initialization (which very much depends on the context), optimizing might yield the same machine code.

Comment: @FelixPalmen It was on purpose that I wrote "it can help" and not "it will answer all your questions" ;)

Comment: Well, the important thing here is that "assignment during definition" doesn't exist. This is *initialization* and it is *indeed* something completely different. I already gave an example where you can observe the difference. Another one would be the attempt to assign to an array -- impossible, although you can of course initialize it.

Comment: "I am reviewing a old codebase ...  if I can get real change by changing the code in all the places." -->Even if there was a difference, it is certainly a micro-optimization - a wee difference.  Given its an "old codebase" presumable functioning fine, is the risk of injecting some functional error due to a mis-edit  and cost of code review, etc. worth this minor improvement?  Perhaps it is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fools_rush_in_where_angels_fear_to_tread)?

Answer (score 4):

The first snippet initializes the variable with a value. The second default-initializes it, which does nothing for a pointer with automatic storage duration, and then assigns a value.

For a non-const pointer with automatic storage duration, there should be no difference except that you may unintentionally use it before it is initialized, which would be UB.

Other things like references or constants for example require the first style.

Answer (score 0):

depends on whether it is local or global

```
int hello;
int world=6;
void fun ( void )
{
    int foo;
    int bar=5;
    foo=4;
    hello=2;
}
```

for globals hello would land in .bss (which may require bootstrap code to set to zero) and the code would be created that executes runtime to set that "variable" to 2.  world would land in .data and have the initial value of 6 set at compile time.  The allocated memory/data space would have that value, but there may be bootstrap required to place that data before use.

foo and bar are ideally on the stack, which is a runtime "allocation" so in either case code is required to make room for them as well as runtime set them to a value.  If you made them static or basically "local globals" they now fall into the same category as globals landing in .bss or .data bar being initialized to 5 the one time but foo being set at runtime in the .text code generated.

simple examples, compiling and disassembling will show how all of this works, granted not trivial as an optimizer may eliminate some of what you are looking for depending on the rest of the code.  (the code above sets hello to 2, foo and bar are dead code and would be optimized out).

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e3a02002    mov r2, #2
   4:   e59f3004    ldr r3, [pc, #4]    ; 10 <fun+0x10>
   8:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
   c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  10:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0

Disassembly of section .data:

00000000 <world>:
   0:   00000006    andeq   r0, r0, r6
```

If I do a very crude link without startup code, etc to see the rest of the picture:

```
00001000 <fun>:
    1000:   e3a02002    mov r2, #2
    1004:   e59f3004    ldr r3, [pc, #4]    ; 1010 <fun+0x10>
    1008:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
    100c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
    1010:   00011018    andeq   r1, r1, r8, lsl r0

Disassembly of section .data:

00011014 <__data_start>:
   11014:   00000006    andeq   r0, r0, r6

Disassembly of section .bss:

00011018 <__bss_start>:
   11018:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

we see both hello and world but foo and bar are optimized out.

Comment: C++ would behave the same.  It is certainly possible for a compiler to see for example if you assigned a value to hello on entry in main() and then never had hello on the left side of the equals sign again and only ever appears in main() that perhaps it could be assigned that value in .data.  it would take a whole binary optimization (rather than per object which is far more typical), and possible that the language would interfere with that optimization.